# Xpath that checks element does not contain a specific src attribute in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Trying to find element **without** a specific img src, but is grabbing all elements in variable not the ones I want, also causing the loop to loop indefinitly

```
  $books = '<div> stuff heer < img src ="/assets/images/post/books.svg"/ ></div>';             
$books2 = array();
                  foreach($books as $v)
                  {
                        $dom = new DOMDocument;
                        @$dom->loadHTML($v);
                        $xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
                        $div = $xpath->query('//*[not(contains(src,"/assets/images/post/books.svg"))]');    
                        foreach ($div as $a) {
                            if(!empty($a))
                            {
                                $books2[] = $v;
                            }
                        }                   
                  }     var_dump($books2); //problem is that this dumps all elements from initial books array and also oddly loops indefinitely..
```

**however**, if I try the code below it works perfectly and outputs correct.. any ideas why above doesnt work?

```
     $books2 = array();
      foreach($books as $v)
      {
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            @$dom->loadHTML($v);
            $xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
            $div = $xpath->query('//*[@src="/assets/images/post/books.svg"]');    
            foreach ($div as $a) {
                if(!empty($a))
                {
                    $books2[] = $v;
                }
            }                   
      }     var_dump($books2);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a issues with the code; the first being that `src` and `@src` are two different things, the former being an element and the latter an attribute.

Secondly, the query is not restricted enough; it queries all nodes that do not have a `src` attribute, whereas you're only interested in finding images, i.e.:

```
//img[not(contains(@src,"/assets/images/post/books.svg"))]
```

Lastly, from your question it seems that you're interested in knowing whether there is at least one such element present, in which case you don't have to do any inner loops:

```
$n = $xpath->query('//img[not(contains(@src,"/assets/images/post/books.svg"))]')->length;

if ($n) {
    $books2[] = $v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did stop the indefinite loops but the not contain part isnt filtering to show data without that src, it just outputs everything unfiltered

Comment: @user2885731 Sorry, but it works with the input provided. Find a better example or find out where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the first code block, you are missing `@` when referencing the src attribute.

This makes the expression select all of elements that do not contain a src ***element*** containing "/assets/images/post/books.svg" (which is all elements in the document), instead of selecting the elements that have a src attribute who's value does not contain that string. 
However, that will still select most of the elements in the document.

You want to select all of the elements ***that have a `@src`*** and ensure that the `@src` attribute's value does not contain that path:

```
//*[@src[not(contains(.,"/assets/images/post/books.svg"))]]
```

Comment: Did that but still doing the same thing, but strangley it works fine in the second block of code when I try to find the elements that DO contain the src ... any ideas?

Comment: I hadn't looked closely enough. Your expression was still too generic. Finding all elements that do not have an @src containing that value, but that would still be almost all of the elements in the document. If you restrict to documents that have an `@src`, and then test the attribute to ensure that it does not contain the path to the image it probably will give you what you want.